# Enable C++ exceptions in Visual Studio 2010 compilation options

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, c++11

I'm trying to compile this source code :

```
// exception_set_unexpected.cpp
// compile with: /c /EHsc
#include<exception>
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;

void unfunction( ) 
{
   cout << "I'll be back." << endl;
   terminate( );
}

int main( ) 
{
   unexpected_handler oldHand = set_unexpected( unfunction );
   unexpected( );
}
```

How can i add `compile with: /c /EHsc` option in Visual Studio 2010 ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Right click on your project -> Properties -> Configuration Properties -> C/C++ -> Command Line

Put your flags in the command Line

Comment: This could only qualify as a "backup plan" since most of the flags are available by setting other options.

Answer (score 4):

> **To set this compiler option in the Visual Studio development environment**
>
> 1. Open the project's Property Pages dialog box. For details, see [How to: Open Project Property Pages.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e79xc5h1.aspx)
> 2. Click the C/C++ folder.
> 3. Click the Code Generation property page.
> 4. Set Enable C++ Exceptions to Yes (/EHsc).
> 5. Click the Command Line property page.
> 6. Type the compiler option in the Additional Options box (/c).

More info [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/19z1t1wy.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

The "/EHsc" option is in the "Code Generation" section of the project settings.

The "/c" option, i'm not certain what is it (the "keep comments" one ?) ?

or maybe I'm mis-reading the original question.

M.